# Message.show based on exception.Message

Tags: c#, message, show

I made registration form. Some features for creating account must be unique. For example username. It is typed in TextBox named "userreg". I would like to create custom message if duplicate username is enter when trying to create a new account. For this demonstration I will use username Admin.

Default:
Message.Show(ex.Message)

I get:
Duplicate entry 'Admin' for key 'username_UNIQUE'

So I made:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.Message == "Duplicate entry ''" + userreg_text.Text + "'' for key 'username_UNIQUE'")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Username already exists");
    }
}
```

Nothing happens. No message displayed.

Any solution would be great.

Comment: You're using the apostrophe twice at 'Admin' (in your case ''Admin'').
Furthermore I wouldn't do it that way.
Check for the entry in your DB and let the MessageBox display if the return value is not NULL.

Comment: there's definitely a better way to handle that scenario

Comment: How do you know `ex.Message ==` will ever be set to what you are attempting to?  Also, failing to log in won't necessarily cause an exception to be thrown.  Your `if` block would be better served in your `try` statement.

Comment: Thank Janes Abou Chlein! It worked ... "Duplicate entry '" + userreg_text.Text + "' for key 'username_UNIQUE'") is correct answer.

Comment: All right, you're welcome. Glad I could help. I added an answer below, you might want to accept it since it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception that is thrown, has the following `Message`:

> Duplicate entry 'Admin' for key 'username_UNIQUE'

You are using this `"Duplicate entry ''" + userreg_text.Text + "'' for key 'username_UNIQUE'"`, which will result into:

> Duplicate entry ''Admin'' for key 'username_UNIQUE'

You're using the apostrophe twice at `'Admin'`.

Use this instead:

`"Duplicate entry '" + userreg_text.Text + "' for key 'username_UNIQUE'"`

As stated above by [Jonesy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1786428/jonesy) and me there are definately better ways to handle that scenario.

For example you could search for the entry (in your case: username 'Admin') in your DB and let the MessageBox display if the return value is not NULL.